# Convert list of objects to dictionary, with unique attributes as keys and associated attributes as values, using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list, that I've like to convert into a dictionary (with unique `B` values used as the keys and a list of corresponding `C` values as the values), as shown below. I'd like to do this using Linq. Is it possible?

```
List<A> input = new() {
   new A() {B=1, C=1},
   new A() {B=1, C=20},
   new A() {B=3, C=5},
   new A() {B=6, C=10},
   new A() {B=6, C=12},
   new A() {B=6, C=30}
}
Dictionary<int,List<int>> result = new() {
   1, List<int>(){1,20},
   3, List<int>(){5},
   6, List<int>(){10,12,30}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just one line of code

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> result = input
    .GroupBy(i => i.B)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(i => i.C).ToList());
```